# if else statement - based on iFrame content?

Tags: javascript

I have a label in navigational breadcrumb:

```
<li>Eligibility</li>
```

Please keep in mind, i am very new learning .NET.

On this page there is iFrame content, where you click a link to view the respective content:

```
<ul id="ss-categories" >
  <li class="eligibility">
    <a href="#"  onclick="ChangeFrame('mem_eligibility.aspx');")>Eligibility</a href>
  </li>
  <li class="deductible">
    <a href="#"  onclick="ChangeFrame('mem_deductible.aspx');")>Deductible</a href>
  </li>
  <li class="claims"><a href="#"  onclick="ChangeFrame('mem_claims.aspx');")>Claims &amp; EOBs</a href>
  </li>
  <li class="benefits">
    <a href="#"  onclick="ChangeFrame('mem_benefits.aspx');")>Benefits</a href>
  </li>
  <li class="hospital">
    <a href="#"  onclick="ChangeFrame('mem_priorAuth.aspx');")>Hospital Admissions</a href>
  </li>
  <li class="priorauth">
    <a href="#"  onclick="ChangeFrame('mem_Inpatient.aspx');")>Prior Authorizations</a href>
  </li>
```

And the iFrame displays the content based on the link you click:

```
<iframe id="ctl00_middleContent_frame1" style="float:left" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" height="400" width="100%" src="mem_eligibility.aspx">
```

In that navigational breakcrumb at the top, how would i code it so that it will change, based on the section of content displayed in the iFrame.

i.e. (in lehmans terms)

```
if iFrame src="mem_elibigility.aspx" {

document.write = 'Eligibility'
}

if iFrame src="mem_deductible.asps" {
document.write = 'Deductible'
}
```

Hope that makes sense, and yes i know my code is complete garbage... and is not structured right, but thats not my job at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Version:**

The following stores the urls that control your iFrame as title attributes and it uses jQuery to set the title of your "header" area. I tried to clean up a bit of the code as well, but this should work for exactly what you need:

**jQuery (Example):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#ss-categories li').click(function()
                                {
                                   var test = $(this).text();
                                   $("#title").text(test);
                                   //Code to change iframe based on property of the item clicked goes here
                                   var title = $(this).attr("title");
                                    $('#ctl00_middleContent_frame1').attr('src', title);
                                });
});
```

**HTML (Example):**

```
<ul id="ss-categories" >
  <li class="eligibility" title="mem_eligibility.aspx">
    <a href="#">Eligibility</a>
  </li>
  <li class="deductible" title="mem_deductible.aspx">
    <a href="#">Deductible</a>
  </li>
  <li class="claims" title="mem_claims.aspx">
      <a href="#">Claims &amp; EOBs</a>
  </li>
  <li class="benefits" title="mem_benefits.aspx">
    <a href="#">Benefits</a>
  </li>
  <li class="hospital" title="mem_priorAuth.aspx">
    <a href="#">Hospital Admissions</a>
  </li>
  <li class="priorauth" title="mem_Inpatient.aspx">
    <a href="#">Prior Authorizations</a>
  </li>


    <li id="title" style="font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold">Eligibility</li>
<iframe id="ctl00_middleContent_frame1" style="float:left" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" height="400" width="100%" src="http://www.google.com">
```

Try this demo to see if that is the functionality you want : [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8MuRn/7/)

**Older answer:**

Is something like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8MuRn/4/) what you are looking for?

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#ss-categories li').click(function()
                                {
                                   var test = $(this).text();
                                   $("#title").text(test);
                                   //Insert logic here to change iFrame based on clicked item
                                });
});
```

It creates a function that will grab the "name" of one of your links in the list and it will display that in your "title" area. If I understood you correctly - I think this will do what you need.